# What is "Great engineering culture" for an SO Jobs listing?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

One of the filtering options offered by Stack Overflow Jobs is "Great engineering culture". It's listed under the "Perks" dropdown:

[image]

It sounds nice, but what does it actually mean? There was no tooltip or help page that I could find. I selected it and looked at a few of the results but none of them actually explained what makes their engineering culture great. I couldn't even tell if this is an option that the job poster sets or if SO staff are enabling it for jobs that meet certain criteria.

After comparing some "Great engineering culture" jobs and non-"Great engineering culture" jobs I didn't see many consistent differences. My best guess is that the "great" jobs have Joel Test scores of 12 or 11, and tend to be at bigger companies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Great engineering culture" refers to jobs where the Joel Test score is 10 or higher.

Comment: Is it, though??

Comment: Yesterday was the 20th anniversary of [the Joel Test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) and [I wrote a blog post about it](https://thomasjowens.com/posts/twentieth-anniversary-of-the-joel-test/). Only 8 of the 12 questions are still relevant today, at best. There are also several aspects of engineering culture, such as onboarding, career development, diversity and inclusion, and continuous improvement that are not part of the Joel Test. Do you think that, in 2020, scoring well on the Joel Test is indicative of "great engineering culture"?

Comment: My question was "what does the flag with this name currently actually indicate", not "is the name appropriate for the way it's being used", so this is a valid answer. I wish it came with a citation, though.

Comment: @SOLO John's profile indicates that he is Staff. However, he doesn't indicate which team he is on. This may be technically correct, it's very misleading if this is indeed the correct answer. That leads to my comments and very likely the down votes.

Comment: yes, I am an engineer on the Talent (aka Jobs) team and checked the code directly to verify this answer.  I will also pass along the feedback about the Joel Test's relevance.

Comment: @ThomasOwens great blog post!

Comment: @ThomasOwens I see, I didn't look at that, thanks. Would have thought the UI would denote staff status more directly.

Comment: @ThomasOwens by the way your comment would make a good question of its own if you're up for it.

Comment: I also think the Joel Test should be revisited, some of the points just aren't relevant to any place I've worked, some of them would be detrimental to products I've worked on.